# "gehört" vs. "gehört zu"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, meaning, difference

Welches von diesen beiden ist korrekt oder wird häufiger gebraucht?
"Es gehört jemandem" oder "es gehört zu jemandem"

Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, wird "es gehört jemandem" als "it's his" übersetzt und "es gehört zu jemandem" als "it belongs to him".
Stimmt meine Vermutung?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gehören + Dativ** drückt Besitz / Eigentum aus.

> Wem gehört dieser Hund?

**Gehören zu** drückt aus, dass etwas für etwas erforderlich ist:

> Zu diesem Beruf gehört eine Menge Ausdauer.

oder, dass etwas ein Teil von etwas ist:

> Ich gehöre zu denen, die sehr früh aufstehen.

oder, dass etwas an eine bestimmte Stelle passt:

> Deine Bemerkung gehört nicht zum Thema.

Comment: Jetzt ist mir klar. Du hast ja recht, habe ich ganz falsch verstanden. Mir ist etwas peinlich.

Comment: Es braucht dir nicht peinlich zu sein. Rom wurde nicht an einem Tag erbaut :) Man lernt nie aus.